# create a listbox that combines data from two tables for a report

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

In Microsoft Access, I am trying to create a report by combining data from two tables in to a listbox:

Table One Holds the ISBN (which is like the bookID):

tbl_StudentOrderLine:

```
   ISBN  Qty  Price  StudentPurchaseID
    1224  1    6         12
```

tbl_Books:

```
ISBN  BookTitle  Author
1224    Random   Someone
```

I would like to produce listbox to show the details for each book where the ISBN matches the ISBN  in the tbl_StudentOrderLine and the only ISBNs shown are the ones with StudentPurchaseID = 12

It doesn't have to be a listbox to show the results, any ideas will be helpful

I have tried a UNION ALL and Have tried creating multiple listboxes but nothing seems to work so any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a JOIN?

Something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_StudentOrderLine sol INNER JOIN
        tbl_Books b ON  sol.ISBN = b.ISBN
WHERE   so.StudentPurchaseID = 12
```

Have a look at this tutorial, always helpfull.

[Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: thankyou for your reply! This was the solution, the actual problem was that in the listbox properties only one column was set to show also!